# I created this code in Visual.Net and it gives an error message This is the error

Tags: vb.net

I created this code in VB.Net and it gives an error message. This is the error in this sentence `Dim resp As Dynamic = JObject.Parse(response.Content)`.

```vb
Private Function GetBearerToken() As String
    Try
        Dim client = New RestClient(Config_class.tokenurl)
        Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" & client_id & "&client_secret=" + client_secret, ParameterType.RequestBody)
        Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)

        Dim resp As Dynamic = JObject.Parse(response.Content)
        Dim token As String = resp.access_token
        Return token
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Return ""
End Function

Private Function GetBearerToken() As String
    Try
        Dim client = New RestClient(Config_class.tokenurl)
        Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" & client_id & "&client_secret=" + client_secret, ParameterType.RequestBody)
        Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)

        Dim resp As Dynamic = JObject.Parse(response.Content)
        Dim token As String = resp.access_token
        Return token
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Return ""
End Function
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You've included the same code snippet twice.

Comment: If you have tried to convert C# code to VB.NET, the corresponding Type of `dynamic` is `Object`, with `Option Strict` set to `Off` (set only in the file that contains this code). It's called *Late Binding* -- You should deserialize your JSON to a class model to better handle its content

Answer (score 0):

What is 'Dynamic'? Try 'JObject' as the type, according to the documentation for JObject:

```
Dim resp As JObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content)
```

Comment: If you change to JObject this code  (Dim token As String = resp.access_token)  it gives an error

Comment: JObject.Parse parses a JObject which alows you view manipulate the JSON at a low level. To keep the same code you would to use the JSON serializer witha class that the properties for the response.

Comment: Please is there a solution